# sscanf - varying number of format arguments?

Tags: c, scanf

In my program, I use `sscanf` to check whether a string is of a given format. To do so, I provide the number of arguments in the format string and check whether `sscanf` returns that same number when parsing the input.

As part of a primitive parser, I want to check whether a string matches one of *many* formats. The `sscanf` function is variadic, so how do I deal with the varying number of arguments I need to pass?

Currently, I just pass a very large number of arguments (e.g. 50) to the function, and just hope that the format strings don't contain more arguments.

Is there any better way to do this?

Comment: @Hogan: Afaik regexes are not part of the C standard library.

Comment: @ryyst They aren't standard c, but they are POSIX

Comment: @ryyst: Check out `man 3 regexec`.

Comment: @ryyst - so?  This is the best way to solve the problem, use a regex library and be happy.  afaict you did not say you were constrained to only standard C library.

Comment: [Sounds like lexing.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis) sscanf won't work too well. Use regex.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You really need something heavier than `scanf`. You have to *tell* `scanf` what format your input is in; it can't figure anything out on its own.

If you have access to POSIX, look at `regex.h` it's probably everything you need.

Otherwise, you're stuck rolling your own. `lex` and `yacc` are nice if the format is rather complex, but otherwise, either `strtok` or (`getchar`+`switch`) is probably the way to go.

**Edit:**
Since you can use POSIX, here's an simple example of how to extract data from a regex in c. (error checking excluded for brevity.)

```
char txt[] = "232343341235898dfsfgs/.f";
regex_t reg;
regmatch_t refs[MAX_REFS]; //as in, the maximum number of data you want to extract
regcomp(&reg, "3433\\([0-5]*\\).*", 0); //replace 0 with REG_EXTENDED if desired
regexec(&reg, txt, MAX_REFS, refs, 0);
regfree(&reg);

txt[refs[0].rm_eo+1] = '\0';
int n = atoi(txt+refs[0].rm_so);
printf("%d\n", n);
```

Prints

```
41235
```

Comment: I have access to POSIX, so `regex.h` would be my next choice. Can I parse the input into different variables with `regex.h`, like `sscanf` does, or will I have to use both `regex.h` and `sscanf`?

Comment: all you need is `regexec`. I'll add an example

Answer (score 1):

You can write a validation function using the variable length arguments using the macros available in `stdarg.h`.

For example,

```
int my_validation_func(const char *format, ...) {
    va_list ap;
    char *p, *sval;
    int ival;
    float fval;

    va_start(ap, format);
    for(p=format; *p ; p++) {
        if (*p != '%') {
            continue;
        }
        switch(*++p) {
            case 'd':
                ival = va_arg(ap, int);
                break;

            case 'f':
                fval = va_arg(ap, float);
                break;

            case 's':
                for (sval = va_arg(ap, char *); *sval; sval++);
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }
    va_end(ap);
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use lex/yacc to build a proper parser. Alternatively, first tokenizing the string with `strtok` might simplify your problem. (Beware: It is really tricky to use `strtok` correctly -- read its documentation very carefully.)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it answers your question, but [you use `varargs` in C](http://c-faq.com/~scs/cclass/int/sx11b.html) to allow a variable number of arguments to a function.

```
void myscanf(const char *fmt, ...)
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The unhelpful answer is "don't do that, write a parser properly, maybe using `lex` and/or `yacc` or `bison`".

The answer to the question you asked is "yes, you could do that". I don't believe there's any reason why there can't be *more* variadic parameters than the format requires, although to few would be a bad thing. I'm presuming that you have an array or list of possible formats and you're calling sscanf in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know *when you're writing the code* the number and type(s) of the arguments, `sscanf()` cannot safely do what you're trying to do.

Passing 50 arguments to `sscanf()` is ok (arguments not consumed by the format string are evaluated but otherwise ignored), but the arguments that correspond to the format string have to be of the expected type, after promotion; otherwise, the behavior is undefined.  So if you want to detect whether a string can be scanned with either `"%d"` or `"%f"`, you can't safely do it with a single `sscanf()` call.  (It's likely you could get away with passing a `void*` that points to a sufficiently large buffer, but the behavior is still undefined.)

Another nasty problem with `sscanf()` is that it doesn't handle numeric overflow.  This:

```
char *s = "9999999999999999999999999";
int n;
int result = sscanf(s, "%d", &n);
printf("result = %d, n = %d\n", result, n);
```

has undefined behavior (assuming 9999999999999999999999999 is too big to be stored in an `int`).

Something you *might* be able to do is find an open-source `sscanf` implementation and modify it so it just verifies the string against the format, without storing anything.  (Dealing with the license for the implementation is left as an exercise.)  This makes sense if you find `sscanf`-style format strings particularly convenient for your problem.  Otherwise, regular expressions are probably the way to go (not in the C standard, but it's easy enough to find an implementation).